# How can I programmatically find the line numbers around Git conflicts?

Tags: git

I'm working on a script that is meant to help people I work with to take a list of merge commits and branch names, rebase them on top of a given tag, and merge the rebased versions together.

One of the biggest issues in that process is that selecting the merge commits and branches is ultimately a manual process, and it's easy to miss one or two. For instance, given a `Base --- ... --- A --- ... --- C` chain of commits, if the user wants to rebase commits on top of Base but only picks C, rebasing is going to fail because C builds upon A. When that happens, you get a merge conflict.

Given this, my desired outcome is that the script tries to figure out what's missing and says "hey, maybe you need to grab commit A too". This doesn't have to work all the time, but getting it right maybe 75% of the time would be really helpful. Unfortunately, I'm struggling on the implementation here. In a longer chain, such as `Base --- ... --- A --- B --- C`, it's possible that B and C are fully independent, but that C still builds upon A. That means that I can't just tell the user to grab all the commits from Base to C (because it pulls in unnecessary changes) which sadly eliminates several simple-ish solutions.

One solution which I believe would work is to check the conflict areas and find the line numbers associated with it in C, and `blame` to find which commits between Base and B have modified these areas. However, the issue here is that when you use `merge` or `rebase`, Git does not put the line numbers associated to conflicting regions in their respective files. For instance, if I had something like this, I could easily achieve my goal:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD file.txt 10 10
Hello world
=======
Goodbye
>>>>>>> 77976da file.txt 10 10
```

where "77976da file.txt 10 10" says "starts at line 10, finishes at line 10 of file.txt on commit 77976da". If I had this information, I could easily `blame` file.txt around the correct lines and see which commit(s) between Base and B have modified them. Instead, I get something that's closer to this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
Hello world
=======
Goodbye
>>>>>>> 77976da
```

which basically tells me nothing. I can't track lines easily because Git merges all non-conflicting parts of the file together without leaving markers, so a conflict marker at line 100 doesn't mean that the conflicting content was on line 100 of either files being merged, and I don't have a way to track how auto-applied merges impact line numbers across the two files being merged.

Is there a way to get the information that I'm after?

Comment: It is not clear to me why you want line numbers along with the conflict markers.  Typically you (or your IDE) would just search for the `<<<<<<<` markers.  Why do you need line numbers?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I want line numbers because I want to *programmatically* blame the file around that area and *programmatically* determine which other commit the person using the script would need to include in their list to not get a conflict. There's no IDE involved in this process.

Comment: For the first requirement, you may simply parse the file in conflict in the working directory, and identify the line numbers of the conflict markers.  For the second part, there is no way to generally do this in a way that would always work.

Comment: Would setting [`merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_conflicts_are_presented) help you any? That way you also have the original text.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I believe that I've explained why I can't do the first one: "I can't easily track lines easily because Git merges all non-conflicting parts of the file together without leaving markers, so I can't do the necessary bookkeeping to figure out what went where on both sides of the file." IOW, other changes that merge just fine should shift line numbers differently on both sides of the merge, but I can't keep track of it. For the second part, I know that I can't always get it right, but getting it right maybe 75% of the time is already a huge time saver at the volume this is needed.

Comment: How would even know that your script got it right?  I mean, code has to be reviewed by humans, this is why you and I draw a salary.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, for the same reason that you use merge tools. You don't "need" help to merge files, you just need to know that they conflict and you'll figure it out, right?

Comment: @Hasturkun, I found that option during my search and I turned it on on my machines, but sadly I haven't been able to think of a way to put it to work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different things going on here, all of which are important.

1. You're not looking at *merge*, you're looking at *cherry-pick*.  (Rebase is repeated cherry-picking.)  Git implements cherry-pick via its merge engine, but the key observation here is that the three inputs to this merge are:

   - the parent of the commit being picked (which goes into index slot 1 as the base);
   - the commit being picked (slot 3 or `--theirs`); and
   - the commit being appended-to (slot 2 or `--ours`).

   You'll need to keep these in mind when looking at part 2.
2. To find the line numbers you care about, you must look at the *merge base* version of the file.  You're essentially repeating the work done by the low-level merge code, so you need all three input files: the merge base version, the `--ours` version, and the `--theirs` version.

   Fortunately, whenever there is a low level merge conflict, Git keeps all three versions of that file in the index, in the three nonzero slot numbers for the file: 1 = base, 2 = ours, and 3 = theirs.

In a normal merge (not a cherry-pick), the merge base is the *best common commit*, which is pretty easy to see in some cases.  For instance, given a history that looks like this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

where the uppercase letters stand in for commit hash IDs, it's clear that the merge base commit, between commits `J` and `L` (or branches `branch1` and `branch2` if you want to think of them this way—although in Git, it's really just all about the *commits*), is commit `H`.

Hence, `git merge` is going to proceed by running two `git diff` operations:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

The merge process simply (or complicated-ly) consists of combining these two sets of differences.  The combined changes get applied, not to the snapshot in `J` or the snapshot in `L`, but rather to the snapshot in `H`.  That way, we get *both* sets of changes applied.

A merge conflict occurs when the "ours" and "theirs" changes either overlap (with the obvious consequences) or "touch at the edges".  The original conflicted source line(s), which will be included if you turn on the `diff3` conflict style option, come from the merge base version of the file.

Since Git leaves all three versions of the file in the index, you can use `git checkout-index --stage=all` to extract the three files (to temporary files with funny `.tmp` names, which get printed to standard output).  Then you can repeat the merge algorithm, comparing the three files and determining when there are overlapping or abutting changes.  These were the sources of your merge conflicts.

The same holds when cherry-picking ... and now the problem you're trying to solve comes in.  If you find the lines that had conflict sources, and you're doing a `git cherry-pick C`, you have this:

```
...--o--D--P--C--o--o   <-- some-label
      \
       E--F--H   <-- current-branch (HEAD)
```

Commit `C` is being copied; commit `P` is being used as the merge base—so all the files in stage 1 are coming from `P`—and commit `H` is the current (HEAD) commit.  A conflict *may* indicate that commit `D` or `P` might be useful to copy-to-add-after-`H` before going on to copy `C`.

But there is no such guarantee.  Perhaps the conflict in obtaining changes from `P` to `C` occurs because the difference between `P` and `E`, or `P` and `F`, irreconcilably changes something: there is some important feature in `E` or `F` that fundamentally conflicts with whatever is being done at `C`.

There's nothing wrong with trying to write a tool to help out here, but note that it's going to be *hard*, and the returns may be small.

Comment: Yes, looking at the git merge source, I was reminded that even if git won’t tell me line numbers, a 3-way merge is pretty much just two diffs being themselves compared. As for returns, our source control process accounts for the fact humans have to do this already, so we’re pretty far from the general case in which anything goes.